# Cannot Add Product to cart

Tags: magento2, addtocart

Whenever I tried to add product to cart from list page or product page in fresh setup **Magento Ce 2.1** release it redirects to checkout page and no product gets added.

I tried disabling cache also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you ran in local and your path is :localhost please replace "localhost" to "127.0.0.1".
**Following:** 
So you can change root URL by SQL query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data 
SET value = 'http://127.0.0.1/' 
WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url');
```

It is sufficient for Magento 1.x but not for Magento 2.0.
Magento 2.0 for some strange purpose additionally stores root URL in the third path: design/head/includes

The record looks like:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="<root URL>/pub/media/styles.css" />
```

**So you need one more SQL query:**

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = REPLACE(value, '<old root URL or domain>', '<new root URL or domain>')
WHERE path = 'design/head/includes';
```

For example:

```
UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = REPLACE(value, 'http://localhost/', 'http://127.0.0.1/')
WHERE path = 'design/head/includes';
```

Then delete the cache:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

Comment: Or read this article to change domain: https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/magento2/change-domain

Comment: Yes you are right. I needed to change localhost to http://127.0.0.1/ and it worked like a charm. Although minicart seems to be not getting updated but my cart issue have been solved. Thanks

Comment: In apache 2.4 you create virtual hosts, so localhost to ip won't work. Secondly in first installation of magento 2.1.8 you don't have 'design/head/includes' in core_config_data. Please update your answer to cater my request too.

Answer (score 1):

Those who don't wish to change the localhost url and doesn't want to add vhost for this problem. Here's the [quick fix](http://magehelper.blogspot.in/2017/03/magento-2-cannot-add-products-to-cart.html).

The problem is due to form_key mismatch. The form key which gets posted during add to cart action is getting mismatched with store session form key.

Go to

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php execute()

method.
and comment out the first If condition.

**NOTE:**This is not a recommended solution for Production environment.

Comment: Please submit the standard solution also

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mac and I faced this issue using localhost as URL for Magento 2 instances. This is a quick fix if you made a new instance and/or trying to debug something quickly...

Following [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/123087/cannot-add-product-to-cart#answer-167088) posted above in this thread fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like it could be a session based issue, are you able to log into the magento admin or a customer account?

Anything in any of the logs pointing towards the add to cart functions?

Comment: I am able to sign in to admin but not customer on front end. once I created customer it was showing every detail of customer now once I logged out and trying login again not working. So how to solve this session based issue. Nothing is in logs also.

Comment: If you clear your browser cache & cookies i should imagine it would work again but will probably stop working after the first attempt to add, you could try switching session storage to database based sessions.